# Angular material set default value for select

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have trouble setting a default value for select on my page. I gather the values from a database, where at the moment I only have one value and that's why I want to set it as default.

here is my code:

```
<mat-form-field appearance="fill">
  <mat-select (selectionChange)="contractSelect($event.value)">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let contractType of contracTypes" [value]="contractType">
      {{contractType.description}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

Comment: are you setting contractType in your ts when you only get one value from your database?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `contractType` exist, you can add a two-way-binding, at `mat-select` like the code bellow:

```
<mat-form-field appearance="fill">
  <mat-select (selectionChange)="contractSelect($event.value)" [(ngModel)]="{{CONTRACT_TYPE_VARIABLE_ON_TS}}">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let contractType of contracTypes" [value]="contractType">
      {{contractType.description}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```